# How to extract substring separated by character?

Tags: iphone

Please tell me how to extract the substring from a single string separated by some character?

**/ 2132321321/34 3/0 /**

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have nonsense words in your question. Please retype and make sure your question is clear.

Comment: automated translation fail. I don't understand at all. Can you retry please?

Comment: Much better :D Will answer

Comment: sorry.. ( I'm not very good English

Comment: Guys, chillax on the guy. He obviously doesn't speak English and has tried to get a translated question. It didn't work and he tried again and got a much better version. No need to downvote.

Answer (score 4):

You can separate the string into an array by doing...

```
NSString *myString = @"/ 2132321321/34 3/0 /";

NSArray *strings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

This will have an array of all the strings like...

```
[@" 2132321321",
 @"34 3",
 @"0 "];
```

You can then do...

```
for (NSString *string in strings) {
    NSLog(@"%i", [string length]);
    // You can do what you want in here.
}
```

This will print all the lengths.

Comment: ))) thanks, Sorry for my english